# Recursively search for each item in txt file in multiple folders

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to do optimized search for each subfolder that not matches my files in my txt file.

Example of txt file:

```
1.2.0.0_009           
1.2.0.0_008           
1.2.0.0_007           
1.2.0.0_006           
1.2.0.0_005           
1.2.0.0_004           
1.2.0.0_003           
1.2.0.0_002           
1.2.0.0_001           
1.1.0.0_106           
1.1.0.0_105           
1.1.0.0_104           
1.1.0.0_103           
1.1.0.0_102           
1.1.0.0_101           
1.1.0.0_100           
1.0.0.0_089           
1.1.0.0_099                    
1.0.0.0_088           
1.0.0.0_087           
1.0.0.0_086           
1.0.0.0_085           
1.0.0.0_084           
1.0.0.0_083           
1.0.0.0_082           
1.0.0.0_081           
1.0.0.0_080           
1.0.0.0_079           
1.0.0.0_078           
1.0.0.0_077           
1.0.0.0_076           
1.0.0.0_075           
1.0.0.0_074           
1.0.0.0_073           
1.0.0.0_072           
1.0.0.0_071           
1.0.0.0_070           
1.0.0.0_069           
1.0.0.0_068           
1.0.0.0_067           
1.0.0.0_066           
1.0.0.0_065           
1.0.0.0_064           
1.0.0.0_063           
1.0.0.0_062           
1.0.0.0_061           
1.0.0.0_060                    
1.0.0.0_052           
1.0.0.0_051           
1.0.0.0_050           
1.0.0.0_049           
1.0.0.0_048           
1.0.0.0_047           
1.0.0.0_046           
1.0.0.0_045           
1.0.0.0_044           
1.0.0.0_043           
1.0.0.0_042           
1.0.0.0_041           
1.0.0.0_040           
1.0.0.0_039           
1.0.0.0_038           
1.0.0.0_037           
1.0.0.0_036_1         
1.0.0.0_036              
0.0.0.1_89            
0.0.0.1_88            
0.0.0.1_87            
0.0.0.1_86            
0.0.0.1_85_1          
0.0.0.1_85            
0.0.0.1_84            
0.0.0.1_83            
0.0.0.1_82            
0.0.0.1_81            
0.0.0.1_80_1          
0.0.0.1_80            
0.0.0.1_79_1          
0.0.0.1_79            
0.0.0.1_78            
0.0.0.1_77            
0.0.0.1_76            
0.0.0.1_75            
0.0.0.1_74            
0.0.0.1_73            
0.0.0.1_72            
0.0.0.1_71            
0.0.0.1_70            
0.0.0.1_69            
0.0.0.1_68            
0.0.0.1_67            
0.0.0.1_66            
0.0.0.1_65            
0.0.0.1_64            
0.0.0.1_63            
0.0.0.1_62            
0.0.0.1_61            
0.0.0.1_60            
0.0.0.1_59            
0.0.0.1_58            
0.0.0.1_57            
0.0.0.1_56            
0.0.0.1_55            
0.0.0.1_54            
0.0.0.1_53            
0.0.0.1_52_1          
0.0.0.1_52            
0.0.0.1_51            
0.0.0.1_50            
0.0.0.1_49            
0.0.0.1_48            
0.0.0.1_47_1          
0.0.0.1_47            
0.0.0.1_46            
0.0.0.1_45            
0.0.0.1_44_1          
0.0.0.1_44            
0.0.0.1_43_1          
0.0.0.1_43            
0.0.0.1_42            
0.0.0.1_41            
0.0.0.1_40            
0.0.0.1_39            
0.0.0.1_38            
0.0.0.1_37            
0.0.0.1_36            
0.0.0.1_35            
0.0.0.1_34            
0.0.0.1_33            
0.0.0.1_32            
0.0.0.1_31_1          
0.0.0.1_31            
0.0.0.1_30            
0.0.0.1_29            
0.0.0.1_28            
0.0.0.1_27            
0.0.0.1_26            
0.0.0.1_25            
0.0.0.1_24            
0.0.0.1_23            
0.0.0.1_22            
0.0.0.1_21            
0.0.0.1_20            
0.0.0.1_19            
0.0.0.1_18            
0.0.0.1_17            
0.0.0.1_168           
0.0.0.1_167           
0.0.0.1_166           
0.0.0.1_165           
0.0.0.1_164           
0.0.0.1_163           
0.0.0.1_162           
0.0.0.1_161
```

Now the first digits represnts folder (for e.g. 1.2.0.0 is a folder) which contains files (009,008, etc...). But also that folder contains **and other files that are not contained in my txt file**. I want to compare this txt file with each folder in my MainFolder:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       11/22/2018   1:04 PM                0.0.0.1
d-----       11/22/2018   1:04 PM                1.0.0.0
d-----       11/22/2018   1:04 PM                1.1.0.0
d-----       11/22/2018   1:04 PM                1.2.0.0
-a----       11/13/2018  11:54 AM          70656 DbUp.dll
-a----       11/13/2018  11:54 AM         230912 DbUp.pdb
```

and copy only those which are not contained in txt file.

My Approach:

```
[string]$SourceTxtDbFile = "C:\file.txt"
$delimitedFile = Get-Content $SourceTxtDbFile | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "_" -PropertyNames DbVersion, ScriptNumber

#foreach file in $delimitedFile
foreach ($file in $file_list){
# foreach file in the folders
foreach($dir in (Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse)){
    # if the file name is in diretocry listed
    if($file -eq $dir.name){
        # copy only once, if the document name already exists, skip
        if(-not(test-path "$destination\$file")){
            # copy the file
            Copy-Item $dir.fullname -Destination $destination -Verbose
        }
     }
   }
}
```

But I assume that it can be more optimized code.

UPDATE:
By the courtesy of @LotPings
Here is the working code (edited by myself):

```
 $uatScripts = (Get-Content $uatFile).Trim() # there were trailing spaces

Push-Location $source

Get-ChildItem *\* -File | ForEach-Object {
    $LookUp = "{0}" -f $_.BaseName
    If ($uatScripts -notcontains $LookUp) {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $destination
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, I want to check all my folders do they have some file that isn't in the txt file. And if they do, to copy-item somewhere in new folder

Comment: If you want to improve your allready working code, try to post it in the CodeReview Page: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Paxz thanks, I know, but I am not sure if there any bugs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are all the files placed directly under the `0.0.0.x` folders or are there subfolder inside the main folders??

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen there are multiple folders inside main foilder. please refer to my question, you will see tha tree directory of the main folder. Inside of each x.x.x.x folders there are only sql files, so, there no folders of the depth of 2

Comment: Then you don't need `-Recurse` - you can just do `Test-Path $source\$dbversion\$scriptnumber` for each file intry

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I didnt understand you. If you want you can write a answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO your script takes a wrong approach,

- I'd keep the content of `$SourceTxtDbFile` as is and
- build corresponding entries from directory and file name
  (where it is unclear if the files have an extension)

**EDIT: With this shorted `file.txt`**

```
0.0.0.1_86            
0.0.0.1_85_1          
0.0.0.1_85            
0.0.0.1_163           
0.0.0.1_162           
0.0.0.1_161
```

and this tree on my ramdrive a:

```
> tree a:\ /f
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
Volumeseriennummer : 5566-7788
A:\
│   file.txt
│
└───0.0.0.1
        161
        162
        163
        164
        165
        82
        83
        84
        85
        85_1
```

This slightly changed script

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\22\SO_53431173.ps1

$source = "A:\"
Push-Location $Source
$destination = "C:\Test"
$SourceTxtDbFile = ".\file.txt"

$DbVScript = (Get-Content $SourceTxtDbFile).Trim() # there were trailing spaces

Get-ChildItem *\* -File | ForEach-Object{
  $LookUp = "{0}_{1}" -f $_.Directory.Name,$_.Name
  If ($DbVScript -notcontains $LookUp){
      Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $destination -Verbose -WhatIf
  } else {
      "File {0} is in `$DbVScript: {1}" -f $_.FullName,$LookUp
  }
}
```

Returns the following output.
(If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`)

```
> Q:\Test\2018\11\22\SO_53431173.ps1
File A:\0.0.0.1\161 is in $DbVScript: 0.0.0.1_161
File A:\0.0.0.1\162 is in $DbVScript: 0.0.0.1_162
File A:\0.0.0.1\163 is in $DbVScript: 0.0.0.1_163
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei kopieren" für das Ziel "Element: A:\0.0.0.1\164 Ziel: C:\Test\164".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei kopieren" für das Ziel "Element: A:\0.0.0.1\165 Ziel: C:\Test\165".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei kopieren" für das Ziel "Element: A:\0.0.0.1\82 Ziel: C:\Test\82".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei kopieren" für das Ziel "Element: A:\0.0.0.1\83 Ziel: C:\Test\83".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei kopieren" für das Ziel "Element: A:\0.0.0.1\84 Ziel: C:\Test\84".
File A:\0.0.0.1\85 is in $DbVScript: 0.0.0.1_85
File A:\0.0.0.1\85_1 is in $DbVScript: 0.0.0.1_85_1
```

Comment: Thanks. But not good enough. Yout $LookUp variable is doubled like this: "0.0.0.1_0.0.0.1_01" and then when you do a matching it's not good comparison. Also I think that I need to check LookUp in DBVScript not DBVScript in LookUp :)

Comment: That doesn't happen here with my own test. What PowerShell version do you use? The order is correct; you probabply mean `-notin` then it's the reverse order `If ($LookUp -notin $DbVScript)`