# Get-Content splitting but keep leading zeros and split only by first '_' in powershell

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I have some txt data like this:

```
0.0.0.1_03_1          
0.0.0.1_03            
0.0.0.1_02_2_1_3_4          
0.0.0.1_02_1          
0.0.0.1_02            
0.0.0.1_01_1          
0.0.0.1_01
```

What I want to achieve is to separate to two variables (0.0.0.1 and the rest)
I want to split only by first '_' and to kept leading zeros (01 for example)
I am doing like:

```
Get-Content $SourceTxtDbFile | 
  ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "_" -PropertyNames DbVersion, ScriptNumber
```

but the result neither has leading zeros nor are the lines split they way I want them to.

Comment: Why not just: `Get-Content $SourceTxtDbFile | ForEach {$DbVersion, $ScriptNumber = $_.Slpit('_', 2) ...` ?

Comment: @iRon where did you defined DbVersion and ScriptNumber? It is not the same as COnvertFrom-String function..

Comment: As an aside: [`ConvertFrom-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string) provides separator-based parsing as well as _heuristics_-based parsing based on templates containing _example values_. The separator-based parsing applies automatic type conversions you cannot control, and the template language is poorly documented, with the exact behavior hard to predict - it's best to avoid this cmdlet altogether. Also note that it's not available in PowerShell _Core_.

Comment: If you take a different approach (as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53434247/6811411) to your previous question suggests) it might not be neccessary to split your `$SourceTxtDbFile` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TessellatingHeckler's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53433238/45375) shows you how to use the `.Split()` method to perform separator-based splitting that limits the number of tokens returned, which in his solution only splits by the *1st* `_` instance, to return a total of *2* tokens.

As an aside: you can also use PowerShell's own `-split` *operator*, whose use [does have its advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375):

```
$_ -split '_', 2 # in this case, same as: $_.split('_', 2)
```

That said, your later comments suggest that you may be looking to simply remove everything after the *2nd* `_` instance from your input strings.

```
$dbVersion, $scriptNumber, $null  = $_ -split '_', 3 # -> e.g., '0.0.0.1', 03', '1'
```

Note how specifying `$null` as the variable to receive the 3rd token effective *discards* that token, given that we're not interested in it.

To re-join the resulting 2 tokens with `_`, it's simplest to use the `-join` operator:

```
$dbVersion, $scriptNumber -join '_'
```

To put it all together:

```
# Sample array of input lines.
$lines=@'
0.0.0.1_03_1
0.0.0.1_03
0.0.0.1_02_2_1_3_4
0.0.0.1_02_1
0.0.0.1_02
0.0.0.1_01_1
0.0.0.1_01
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# Use Get-Content $SourceTxtDbFile instead of $lines in the real world.
$lines | ForEach-Object {
  # Split by the first two "_" and save the first two tokens.      
  $dbVersion, $scriptNumber, $null = $_ -split '_', 3
  # Re-join the first two tokens with '_'and output the result.
  $dbVersion, $scriptNumber -join '_'
}
```

With your sample input, this yields:

```
0.0.0.1_03
0.0.0.1_03
0.0.0.1_02
0.0.0.1_02
0.0.0.1_02
0.0.0.1_01
0.0.0.1_01
```

Answer (score 6):

Limit the number of splits with `.Split($separator, $count)` and then make your own output objects:

```
Get-Content D:\test.txt | ForEach-Object {

    $Left, $Right = $_.split('_', 2)

    [PsCustomObject]@{ 
        DbVersion    = $Left.Trim()
        ScriptNumber = $Right.Trim()
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am receiving an error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Apparently not all rows contain a `_`, try: "$Left".Trim() and "$Right".Trim()

Comment: @iRon Now, I ahve none output. Not any errors but not output as well.

Comment: Check your input file.

Comment: @iRon I am debugging right now, line: $Left, $Right = $_.split('_', 2) passes. So it isnt about the file..it breaks on [PsCustomObject]

Comment: @Stefan0309 run `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()` and see what powershell version you are using; if it doesn't like PSCustomObject it might be quite old. Current on Windows is version 5.1...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I am using 5.1 powershell version, I can see it at the bottom of my VS Code :) I think the problem is when it try to trim null value...maybe empty row in txt..

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler It works now. I put it into a variable whole thing like $files = Get-Content... and I had empty lines in my txt. Thanks! Just how to sleect one  column with Select-Object?

Comment: `Get-Content $SourceTxtDbFile | ForEach-Object {...` *as in the answer* `...} | Where-Object {$_.DbVersion -eq "1.2.0.0"} | Select-Object {"$($_.ScriptNumber)te"}`, If this doesn't work, try to remove the `Where-Object {...}` cmdlet and see what happens.

Comment: @iRon in this situation I need something like: Select-Object DbVersion_ScriptNumber

Comment: Ok, back to my first suggestion: `Get-Content $SourceTxtDbFile | ForEach {$DbVersion, $ScriptNumber = $_.Slpit('_', 2); "$DbVersion_$ScriptNumber"}`

Comment: Or: `Get-Content $SourceTxtDbFile | ForEach {$DbVersion, $ScriptNumber = $_.Slpit('_', 2); If ($DbVersion -eq '1.2.0.0') {"$($DbVersion)_$ScriptNumber"}}`, bracket for `$($DbVersion)` are required because a "_" can be used for a variable name.

Comment: @Stefan0309 I don't understand, why do you want to split them out and then join them back together again? That seems like the same as doing nothing..

Comment: As an aside, @iRon: `$($DbVersion)` works, but if disambiguating a variable name is all that is needed, `${DbVersion}` is both more efficient and more readable. TessellatingHeckler, my _guess_ is that _in effect_ Stefan just wants to trim everything starting with the _2nd_ `_`, so that `0.0.0.1_02_2_1_3_4 ` turns into `0.0.0.1_02`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative RegEx approach:

```
> gc .\file.txt|?{$_ -match "^([^_]+)_(.*) *$"}|%{[PSCustomObject]@{DBVersion=$Matches[1];ScriptNumber=$Matches[2]}}
```

---

```
DBVersion ScriptNumber
--------- ------------
0.0.0.1   03_1
0.0.0.1   03
0.0.0.1   02_2_1_3_4
0.0.0.1   02_1
0.0.0.1   02
0.0.0.1   01_1
0.0.0.1   01
```

The same without aliases:

```
Get-Content .\file.txt|
  Where-Object {$_ -match"^([^_]+)_(.*) *$"} | 
    ForEach-Object {
      [PSCustomObject]@{
        DBVersion   = $Matches[1]
        ScriptNumber= $Matches[2]
      }
    }
```

The RegEx `"^([^_]+)_(.*) *$"` also removes trailing spaces from your posted sample lines.